# SpringSecurity - Not preventing access after login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use Java configuration for Spring Security using Roles in order to only grant access to authenticated users. The login process is working, but when I log in using a role that should have limited access, I'm still able to get to a route that should be protected. Here's my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class with the http configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataConfig dataConfig;

private final String QUERY_USERS = "select email, password, enabled from Account where email=?";
private final String QUERY_AUTHORITIES = "select a.email, au.authority from Account a, Authority au where a.email = au.email and a.email =?  ";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeUrls()
    .antMatchers("/public/login.jsp").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/public/home.jsp").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()

    .antMatchers("/secured/**").fullyAuthenticated()
    .antMatchers("/resources/clients/**").fullyAuthenticated()
    .antMatchers("/secured/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers("/secured/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

    .and()
     .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
        .failureUrl("/loginfailed")
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")

     .and()
     .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")     // The URL that triggers logout to occur on HTTP POST
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")    // The URL to redirect to after logout has occurred
        .invalidateHttpSession(true);   // Clear the session
}

@Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    // Use the database
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(new org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder()) 
        .dataSource(dataConfig.dataSource())

        .withDefaultSchema()
        .usersByUsernameQuery(QUERY_USERS)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(QUERY_AUTHORITIES);    
    }
}
```

and here is my WebApplicationInitializer class where I register the security filter chain:

```
public class DatabaseWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final Class<?>[] configurationClasses = new Class<?>[] { 
                AppConfig.class, DbConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};

private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    registerListener(servletContext);           
    registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);

    registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
}

private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {

    // creates an application context for direct registration of 
    // @Configuration and other @Component-annotated classes
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = createContext(AppConfig.class);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = createContext(configurationClasses);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}


private void registerSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter(
            BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN, new DelegatingFilterProxy());
    springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    // set the active profile
    context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");

    context.register(annotatedClasses);
    return context;
}
```

}

If I log in using credentials that only have a role of USER (not ADMIN), I can still access the route of **/secured/admin/**** although I think that should be restricted to only those with a role of ADMIN. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or can point me to a good example of this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably confident it is to do with the order of your `.antMatchers()` statements.

You currently have `.antMatchers("/secured/**").fullyAuthenticated()` before `.antMatchers("/secured/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`. Spring Security is probably matching against this first matcher and applying the `fullyAuthenticated()` check, which will mean that authorisation is given if you only have role `USER`.

I would suggest re-ordering things so that your `.antMatchers()` statements are like this:

```
.antMatchers("/public/login.jsp").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/public/home.jsp").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/resources/clients/**").fullyAuthenticated()
.antMatchers("/secured/user/**").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers("/secured/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
.antMatchers("/secured/**").fullyAuthenticated()
```

In this scenario Spring will match earlier rules for specific access to the `/secured/admin/**` and the `/secured/user/**` resources before falling back to the `/secured/**` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. As suggested I have re-ordered the antMatchers() but with no luck.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is caused by the Spring Security version? I currently use 3.2.0.M2. I also tried with 3.2.0.RC1

Comment: If it is possible change the log level to DEBUG. You will see the information you seek there.